# JS jQuery populate input text field with values seperated by a comma by multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, tags

Into the following simple text input...

```
<input id="target" type="text" name="color" value="" placeholder="Enter tags">
```

...should data be added by some independent buttons, like:

```
<button onClick="AddTag('target', 'blue');">blue</button>

<button onClick="AddTag('target', 'yellow');">yellow</button>

<button onClick="AddTag('target', 'green');">green</button>

<script>
    function AddTag(target_element, value){
        // ??
    }
</script>
```

After pressing all buttons, the text field should have the value:

```
blue,yellow,green
```

The added values should be seperated by a seperator like a comma.

Though, it is important that also dublicate values can be added. So let's say all buttons are clicked again, but the second button is clicked 2 times, the text field should show:

```
blue,yellow,yellow,green
```

I know that there are scripts out there like selectize.js and select2, but they don't exactly offer what I need here, since they don't really accept dublicated values properly, and they also let the tags being selected only from a form element, as far as I am aware. But I need them being able to be added from independant buttons placed somewhere on the page, like in the example above.

I hope somebody can help to write a simple function for that.

Edit: It should also be compatible with free typed in tags.

Comment: Every time you click on a button, push the value onto a global array. Then put `array.join(',')` in the input field's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jQuery tag is there so you can easily do:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var Buttontext = $(this).text();
  $('#target').val((($('#target').val() !=='') ? $('#target').val()+','+Buttontext : Buttontext));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="target" type="text" name="color" value="" placeholder="Enter tags">
<button>blue</button>

<button>yellow</button>

<button>green</button>
```